# Life Cycle / Flow control in content Provider?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Can somebody explain me the flow of control in this tutorial : http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#tutorialusecp

I am not able to get the right flow. I am completely a novice to this content provider etc.

I wanted to know when does actually the DB gets created, what are the lifecycle methods and what is the sequence of method execution in this project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the Flow!! :

First of all, the `onCreate` of Content Provider is called just when the application launches as we have registered this in Manifest.

Then, `onCreate` of our first Activity, i.e. `onCreate` of ToDodOverviewActivity.
the call to `fillData()` has the `initLoader()` call which in turn calls the `onCreateLoader` of the Loader.

Then, here at

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            MyTodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

creation of Loader takes place. a loader that queries the ContentResolver and returns a Cursor. This class implements the Loader protocol in a standard way for querying cursors, building on AsyncTaskLoader to perform the cursor query on a background thread so that it does not block the application's UI.

This in turn leads a call to `onCreate()` of DataHelper and ToDoTable etc and here everyone know the flow about SQLiteOpenHelper.

Finally, `onLoadFinished()` gets called which in turn swaps the cursor and updates the adapter.